# Pagination of a search engine

Tags: javascript, jsp, solr, pagination

I am creating a enterprise search engine.  I am using Solr for creating a search engine and SolrJ for front end with JSP. I want apply pagination to my search results. My code for getting the results from solr core is as follows.

```
    while(iter.hasNext())
       {
       SolrDocument doc1 =iter.next();
       String dc =iter.next().toString();

       out.println(doc1.getFieldValue("id"));


       out.println(doc1.getFieldValue("title"));
       out.println("<BR>");
       out.println("content_type :");
       out.println(doc1.getFieldValue("content_type"));  
       out.println("<BR>");
       out.println("doc_type :");
       out.println(doc1.getFieldValue("doc_type"));
        } %>
```

there are 600 records in my search engine. if a search for a specific keyword all the records related to it come on single page. Can any body suggest me any logic for pagination using javascript. i want to use client side pagination. please help.

Answer (score 0):

While creating solr query you can set start and rows e.g:

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery(searchTerm);
query.setStart((pageNum - 1) * numItemsPerPage);
query.setRows(numItemsPerPage);
// execute the query on the server and get results
QueryResponse res = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
```

Also, each time you do iter.next() you are reading next element in the Iterator. Hence by doing

```
SolrDocument doc1 =iter.next();
String dc =iter.next().toString();
```

you are skiping one element. Refer: [here](http://www.pathbreak.com/blog/using-solr-from-java-applications-with-solrj)